# Excel copy and paste rows using loop

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

my questing is about trying to copy and paste 4 rows (4-7) under each row for the entire sheet, maybe using loop. I have pasted the copied rows under row 8 & 13 as an example (I would like to be able to do that for the remaining sheet until the rows are empty). Your expertise is greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oEHX.png)

Comment: You will need to loop backwards for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To implement:

1. Create a second sheet (in my code, referenced as `Sheet2`)
2. Paste the rows on this sheet that are to be inserted on the first sheet
3. Run Macro

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub EnterRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update

Dim i As Long, LR As Long, myRange As Range

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("1:4")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        myRange.Copy
        ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Insert xlDown
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]